# An example of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Is there a metric space in which a ball of larger radius is a proper subset of a ball with smaller radius? If yes, can you provide an example, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** play around with $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: What about the metric?

Comment: The usual one, $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.

Answer (score 1):

In a unit square, take the ball centered at the square's corner. What's the smallest ball that covers that one?

Comment: More precisely, can B(a,2) be a proper subset of B(b,1) for some a and b?

Comment: @user273090 Yes. See (and work on) the [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1446448/152299) by **par**. Not necessarily with radii 2 & 1, though...

Comment: I saw that but could not construct a metric. Would you please give me more hint?

Comment: Use the natural one.

Comment: Let $X=[0,\infty)$ and $d(x,y)=|x-y|.$ Then $B(0,5)=[0, 5)$ and $B(2.5,3)=[0,5.5).$ In that case $B(0,5) \subset B(3,3)$. I got that thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\{0, 3, 6\}$ with the normal metric, now $B_{0;5}=\{0, 3\}$ is a ball of radius 5 centered at 0 and $B_{3;4}\{0, 3, 6\}$ is a ball of radius 4 centered at 3. It's clear that $B_{0;5}\subset B_{3;4}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=[0,1]$ with usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.
Then $B_{1/3}(0)=[0,1/3)$ and $B_{1/4+1/24}(1/4)=[0,1/2+1/24]$.
Hence $\frac{1}{3}>\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{24}$ but $B_{1/3}(0)\subset B_{1/4+1/24}(1/4)$